# VB.net Change specific datagridview row color based on value in array

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

On my form I have a datagridview. I also have a text file with the following values:

```
PersonName:PersonAge:ChampionTrueOrFalse
```

When the sub is called all the values from the text file get loaded into an array, and the first value (Person Name) gets displayed in the datagridview. 
What I am trying to acheive is: if the value of the persons fourth value (ChampionTrueOrFalse) is true, then color the background of that specific row yellow.

The closest i have got is the following, however it is coring ALL cells green when it should only be coloring the cells that have "False" in the column.

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
        For Each row1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row1.Cells("ChampionTrueOrFalse").Value = "Yes" Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to iterate all rows in that event.  The event args will *tell you* which row needs to be painted.  See the dupe

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for this to not work.

```
If something Then DataGridView1.Rows(RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it sorted!

Correct code was:

```
For Each row1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

If row1.Cells("ChampionTrueOrFalse").Value = "True" Then
                row1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gold
End If

Next
```